# Como retornar mas de un valor en mi webservices en c#

Tags: c#, web, webservice

tengo el siguiente caso, tengo un webservices que en uno de los metodos regresa un string el cual es una variable y listo pero ahora me piden que devuelva mas de una pero con diferentes etiquetas

En el primer Cuadro se ve como lo mandaba y en el segundo cuadro se ve como lo debo de mandar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del metodo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo de como lo estoy intentando regresar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero si necesitas regresar más cosas, no puedes crear una clase llamada no sé... _ResponseAPI_ o algo, y en ella, poner una variable para cada cosa que necesites retornar?

Comment: cree una clase con las propiedades que necesita regresar. Investigue acera de POO en C#: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/classes